# Bounding an integral of a product of functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $f_i:[0,1]^d\to[0,\infty)$ be continuous functions such that for every $i,j\in\{1,...,d\}$ and $t\in[0,1]^{d-1}$,
$$\int_{\{t_1\}\times\{t_2\}\times\cdots\{t_{j-1}\}\times[0,1]\times\{t_j\}\times\cdots\times\{t_{d-1}\}}f_i(x)dx\le C$$
where $C$ is independent of $t$, $i$, and $j$.

Is it possible to bound $$\int_{[0,1]^d}\prod_{i=1}^df_i(x)dx$$ in terms of $C$?

I know that the answer is yes if $f_i(x)$ only depends on $x_i$ by moving the product out of the integral but I am wondering if this is true for general $f$ and how to prove this.